# Whats a simple system to keep invoices in Google-sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I run a small business with 5 transactions per day.

I use Google-sheets to create the invoices.
One invoice per sheet.

How can I sort the invoices (sheets) on one of the cells in each sheet?
e.g. The total-owing cell.

This will mean I can sort to find all the invoices where money is owed.

Comment: Please edit your question to a specific problem. See  [how do I ask a good question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Questions looking for opinions are not a good fit.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Henk!
Even it's a small business, you're talking of 25-30 invoices per week, maybe 1.500 a year! It's gonna soon start to be quite uneasy to handle

What I think is preferrable is to use Google Sheets more like a database. You're not meant to store each invoice, but the information of each invoice.

I'd have one sheet that has all the invoices' information. One invoice per row and all the columns you need

Maybe you can have one sheet for clients with their personal information (again, one per row) and another for products or services.

Then, you can have one sheet as a form (or you can actually use Google Forms to do it) where you input the invoice information and copies all that data to the Invoices sheet (you can set a macro to do it, they're easy to record and you don't need to know any coding)

You can have one extra tab to "print" previous invoices (for example, you choose an invoice number and all the data is brought for that Invoices sheet)
One for Payments

And finally, you can have one or more sheets to analyse the information (statistics, filter invoices per customer, invoices which still are owed, etc.)

Briefly, with 6-10 sheets you can handle all the operation of your business, and you'll be able to use Google Sheets at its full potential!!

1. Invoices tab
2. Customer's Tab
3. Product's Tab
4. Form's Tab
5. Payment's Tab
6. Printing Invoices Tab
7. .... Statistics/Dashboards

If you want, you can upload here more question's and I/we can guide you through!